# PID gains from the transfer function of a plant

Tags: matlab, pid-controller

I am trying to calculate gains ( Kp, Ki, Kd ) of a PID controller. I have to improve the response of a plant. I already have the Transfer function of the plant.

I was wondering if matlab has some command for calculation of controller gains ( kp ki and kd ) from the transfer function of the plant and it finds those gains based on certain parameters ( **less than 5% OS, no Steady State error and minimal rise time** )

PS -  I would highly appreciate solutions other than simulink

**EDIT:**

TF = 1.546/s+0.497

Comment: some example data or the transfer function would be nice.

Comment: You can use the [**`pidtool`**](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID) - I don't have it by hand, but maybe you find a way to control it programatically or there could be a button to generate code, which you can modify later on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes matlab has the automatic PID tuning capability.

PID tuning is the process of finding the values of proportional, integral, and derivative gains of a PID controller to achieve desired performance and meet design requirements.

You may check these two links: [link1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/automatic-pid-tuning.html) and [link2](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/pid-tuning.html).

This [example](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID) particularly deals with transfer function and PID controller design.

**Generally:**

To tune the overshoot, you can use phase margin. Typically, higher phase margin improves stability and overshoot, but limits bandwidth and response speed.

For example you can do this:

```
sys = tf(1,[1 3 3 1]);
opts = pidtuneOptions('PhaseMargin',45);
[C,info] = pidtune(sys,'pid',opts);
```

Keep in mind that a higher bandwidth (0 dB crossover of the open-loop) results in a faster rise time, and a higher phase margin reduces the overshoot and improves the system stability. So, you can do this:

```
opts = pidtuneOptions('CrossoverFrequency',32,'PhaseMargin',90);
[C, info] = pidtune(sys, 'pid', opts)
```

On the other hand, A proportional controller **Kp** will have the effect of reducing the rise time and will reduce but never eliminate the steady-state error. An integral control **Ki** will have the effect of eliminating the steady-state error for a constant or step input, but it may make the transient response slower.